# Disabling parsing for all files in a directory on web server

Tags: security, apache, file-upload, execution

Is it possible to tell Apache server to not parse any files in a given directory?

For example, if I want to create a folder, where all uploads reside, and I want to prevent these files parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your upload directory outside of your web root. This is generally better security anyway. If you need to allow http download access to uploaded files, then you can do that via a script.

Alternatively, ensure that your upload script changes the file permission to remove execute privilege. (e.g. `chmod 0644` or `chmod -x`)

Comment: But if I need to give user the ability to dowload that folder afterwards?

Comment: @Rogach - my last edit answers your question. You could use a PHP (or similar) script to read the contents of the file and return it to the visitor.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you upload a file into the folder , after uploading set the file permission only to read and not execute..

Comment: It's already not executable, but apache can still read it and parse php that is contained inside, thus allowing the attacker to execute bad code.

Comment: @Rogach, apache will normally only parse PHP from files with specific filename extensions (e.g. .php, .php5). If your upload script ensures that files do not end with these extensions, then apache will not try to execute as PHP.

Comment: @qbert220 - I know that, and also I know that there are numerous ways to bypass that. I was just searching for a way to forbid parsing of ANY files in a given directory.

Comment: @Rogach - moving your upload directory out of your web root will achieve that. You could override the apache handlers in a .htaccess file, but you are reliant on knowing what is configured in the apache config files. If the apache configuration is updated you would need to update your .htaccess accordingly.